# How to scroll child in a fixed overflow:hidden parent?

Tags: css

I have fixed position parent rotated with an `overflow:hidden`.
I want to have the child element in it able to scroll.

For some reason, even when I declare `overflow: scroll` on the child and height, the scrolling does does occur, just seems to get stuck.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtQmr/)

HTML:

```
<div class="papa">

<div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam debitis ea autem non earum quaerat delectus nostrum laborum dolores et hic omnis enim similique. Aspernatur ipsa laboriosam vel deserunt ut.

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.papa{
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
transform: rotate(3deg);
}

.child{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 10%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `.papa{` height full window size `100%` posible value set, try this way,

#### Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtQmr/2/)

```
.papa{
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, had to set `height` for parent element and it managed to work.
Here is the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtQmr/1/) if anyone will need it.